# Kotlin extensions for Android: How to use bundleOf

Tags: android, kotlin, android-bundle, android-ktx

Documentation says:

```
fun bundleOf(vararg pairs: Pair<String, Any?>): Bundle
```

> Returns a new Bundle with the given key/value pairs as elements.

I tried:

```
val bundle = bundleOf {
  Pair("KEY_PRICE", 50.0)
  Pair("KEY_IS_FROZEN", false)
}
```

But it is showing error.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If it takes a `vararg`, you have to supply your arguments as parameters, not a lambda. Try this:

```
val bundle = bundleOf(
  Pair("KEY_PRICE", 50.0),
  Pair("KEY_IS_FROZEN", false)
)
```

Essentially, change the `{` and `}` brackets you have to `(` and `)` and add a comma between them.

Another approach would be to use Kotlin's `to` function, which combines its left and right side into a `Pair`. That makes the code even more succinct:

```
val bundle = bundleOf(
  "KEY_PRICE" to 50.0,
  "KEY_IS_FROZEN" to false
)
```

Comment: Does this auto converts or check if the variable is `Parcelable` or not?

Answer (score 12):

How about this?

```
val bundle = bundleOf (
   "KEY_PRICE" to 50.0,
   "KEY_IS_FROZEN" to false
)
```

`to` is a great way to create `Pair` objects. The beauty of infix function with awesome readability.

Comment: I have added the plugin `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'` , but `bundleOf()` doesn't resolve itself.  Is there something else to set up?

Comment: bundleOf has nothing to do with android-kotlin-extension. It is part of core library. Ideally it should be available.

Comment: @toobsco42 bundleOf is part of the Android KTX extension functions. Check out the docs here: https://developer.android.com/kotlin/ktx (it's in the androidx.core.os package)

Comment: @toobsco42 change bndleOf import to "androidx.core.os.bundleOf"

Answer (score 11):

Just to complete the other answers:

First, to use `bundleOf`, need to add `implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.0'` to the `build.gradle` then:

```
var bundle = bundleOf("KEY_PRICE" to 50.0, "KEY_IS_FROZEN" to false)
```